# Azure Active Directory Authentication Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, iis, azure-active-directory

We have used azure active directory authentication to authenticate the user. While implementing this functionality in visual studio, it worked fine but when we tried to deploy the app to IIS, we are facing an issue.

The issue is as below:

1) The user is redirected to Microsoft login page for authentication.
2) On entering the credentials on Microsoft login page, the user is redirected back to the app URL.

(Note: I have added the redirect URI to Azure active directory app)

3) So in the successful scenario, it should display App home page. But for our scenario, it is displaying the blank page when we deployed our app to IIS and tested it.

Is there any link which will help with the steps to deploy azure active directory app to IIS?

Could anyone please share your comments/suggestions on the above issue?

Comment: Is your app an Asp.net MVC web app?  [Here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect) is a sample. And you can also refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/vs-active-directory-dotnet-getting-started) and [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/developing-aspnet-apps-with-windows-azure-active-directory)

Comment: Yes. It is a MVC Web App.